# Beta-binomial random number generator

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, matlab

Could someone help me find a random number generator from a Beta-Binomial distribution in MATLAB, R or SAS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia, the [beta-binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_distribution_as_a_compound_distribution) is a [compound distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution), namely, it's like a **binomial distribution** in which the $p$ parameter is randomly drawn from a **beta distribution**.

Matlab's Statistic Toolbox has functions to generate binomial random numbers (`binornd`; see  its [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/binornd.html)) and beta-distributed random numbers (`betarnd`; see its [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/betarnd.html)), so it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yep. Or as a one line anonymous function: `betabinomrnd = @(alp,bet,n,M,N)binornd(n,betarnd(alp,bet,M,N));`, where `alp`, `bet` and `n` are your three parameters and `M` and `N` specify the dimensions of the matrix of samples (the parameters can be scalars or match the dimension of the output here).